# IIS appears to not be authenticating my request

Tags: asp.net, sql, wcf, iis

Okay so full disclosure I am new to IIS and WCF so I bought a book and am stuck.  I can develop on my dev box at work as it is Windows 7 with IIS 7 but at home on Windows 8 and IIS 8 I believe there are two issues and I just do not know which step is potentially causing the issue.  I am developing on .NET 4.5 environment with Visual Studio 2012 Professional for both environments.

Basically I believe IIS to be set up wrong as I am following a book called 'Windows Communication Foundation 4, Step be Step' 
[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Communication-Foundation-Step-Microsoft/dp/0735645566](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735645566)

I followed the set up instructions but they are a little different at home and am curious what to do to correct this error:

"The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' "

This code occurs after I create a WCF service library web project, it is referencing an entity framework model.  You create a console app that references the web service and it runs fine.  You deploy that web service to IIS and change the config file to reference that location and it blows up with the error above ONLY on the windows 8 machine, the Windows 7 runs just fine.

I noticed two steps I could not do in the setup and believe they are the culprits but don't know how to adjust for Windows 8 yet.

1. From VS command prompt: 'aspnet_regiis -iru', this does not work AT ALL for IIS 8.  Don't know what options when you open IIS to set for the generic okays for asp.net operations.  - I did attempt to go into IIS and under 'Authentication' turn on Anonymous authentication and ASP.NET.  Still did not fix anything.
2. The book came with a sql object that then registered two users to the database for 'Adventureworks'.  Obviously I am guessing since part 1 did not work or due to Windows 8 settings these users do not exist, hence they cannot be registered.  The code for the register users is:

'CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
GO
GO
CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0] FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0]
GO'

- I know SQL code but I know that the users don't exist they are trying to reference so may I add them through IIS or through Control Panel?  I was not sure so I did not know IIS so thought I should ask first.

Any help is much appreciated as I know this is probably just a simple method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I got it but not the way I would have hoped to.  It seems that I need to run the service with Anonymous Access in IIS 8.  Go to 'Authentication' under the default site 'disable' ASP.NET impersonation.  But....  for some reason IIS8 and WCF options for .NET 4.5 were not enabled by default for Windows 8.  So I found this: http://proq.blogspot.com/2012/09/wcf-on-iis-and-windows-8.html and enabled them.

Weird, anyways I know at some point I am going to have to register ASP.NET users on my local machine mimicking a server environment.  But for the time being anonymous access seems to work.  I am curious though if IIS knew it had two choices and anonymous was first why it failed?  Does it take the most restrictive policy as the default for an access point binding at all times?  I am completely new to IIS and it seems like I am going to have to learn it as well as the WCF.

EDIT: When running VS 2012 with some settings also be sure to run VS as ADMINISTRATOR or you may also have issues.